# Center object on screen when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page with a list on the right and a treeview on the right, and have a drag and drop interface to move objects from one to the other.  There is a trash can in the middle used to delete items.  Problem is, the page could potentially become 5000px long.  How can I keep the trash can centered in the screen when the user scrolls?  Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css to fix the position of the trash can.

```
.trash-can
{
    position: fixed;
    left: /*value here*/;
    top: /*value here*/;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To keep an element fixed in a particular position, use `position: fixed`, for example:

```
#trashcan {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -100px; /* half the width */
    margin-top: -100px; /* half the height */
}
```

`position: fixed` is a lot like `position: absolute` but with the coordinates/position based on the viewport, not the document. So while `position: absolute` items will scroll with the page, `position: fixed` items will stay in place in relation to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

The css shown works nicely for small objects. By small, I mean, smaller than the screen height. Objects that are larger than the screen height, cannot be scrolled when position:fixed is used.